# How to find specific lessons in Zen Buddhism?

Tags: zen

As an example of what I mean, suppose I want to find Zen Buddhist teachings on diet. How should I go about finding this? Googling anything as it pertains to Buddhism (especially Buddhism) gets a tonne of results from Americanized Yoga types, which is less than authentic teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this glossary page](https://global.sotozen-net.or.jp/eng/library/glossary/index.html) by sotozen-net. You might find it helpful.

Here's the [Zen Buddhism WWW Virtual Library](http://www.ciolek.com/WWWVL-Zen.html) which has some collection of Zen writings.

If you want to go beyond Zen, there's the [AccessToInsight index by subject](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/index-subject.html).

Answer (score 1):

From my U.S. perspective... Try using the word "Dharma" in your search terms. Most large Zen centers have web sites that list recommended reading, and other resources. Focus on translations of, or by ordained Zen Roshis (cross reference American Zen Teachers Association).  Ask a librarian.